# alt + tab displays open windows beneath my active windows (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: shortcut-keys

As mentioned, when I try to alt + tab through my active windows/applications on ubuntu the miniature window which opens that you can tab through to select a different window is displaying beneath my open windows so it's difficult to see what I'm doing unless I first minimise everything and then select what I need.

Perhaps I have incorrectly configured something or need to change something.

I only installed Ubuntu a couple weekends ago and haven't made any real changes. My computer was a new HP Pavilion 550-219na Desktop PC, and it only has Ubuntu running on it.

Thanks if you are able to help!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice this behavior from time to time.  I don't know what causes it, but I have been able to resolve it without booting with:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then type `unity` and press `ENTER`.

Of course, logging out and logging back in also gets things working correctly again.  The `Alt + F2` allows for continuing the current session.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I'm home next if the problem reoccurs.